# How to edit a QTableView

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, qt4

I am currently trying to add editing functionality to a class derived from `QTableView`. I have added a custom delegate that should provide editing functionality. However if I do a simple `qDebug() << "FieldDelegate::createEditor()";` at the beginning of the delegate, I can see that this function never get's called. I tried to look at the examples in the Qt4 documentation and in the book "C++ Gui Programming with QT4", but all I could find were examples for delegates with `QTableWidgets` and not `QTableViews`. However in my case I need a custom data model, so I do not want to replicate any data in `QTableWidgetItems`.

So far I did the following:

- I added the custom delegate using `QAbstractItemModel::setItemDelegate()`
- I activated editing functions using `setEditTriggers( QAbstractItemView::DoubleClicked )`

When I double click on an item nothing happens in this setup. The `FieldDelegate::createEditor()` is not called at all.

I also tried connecting the `doubleClicked()` signal from the `QAbstractItemView` to the `edit()` slot of the same class, but this only gives me the message `edit: editing failed`  whenever I double click on a cell.

So far I do not return anything in other roles than `Qt::EditRole` from the `DatabaseModel::data()` method. This will be similar to the final case, where I want to add an empty row at the bottom of the table that will be used for adding new data. Could this cause the problem?

Here is the code for the construction of the View:

```
DocumentChoiceView::DocumentChoiceView( DatabaseModel * model,
                                          QWidget * parent ) :
    QTableView( parent ),
    m_model( model )
  {
    setShowGrid ( false );
    setModel( m_model );
    setItemDelegate( m_model->delegate().get() );
    setEditTriggers( QAbstractItemView::DoubleClicked );
    connect( this, SIGNAL(doubleClicked(const QModelIndex&)), 
             this, SLOT(edit(const QModelIndex&)) );
    verticalHeader()->hide();
  }
```

Comment: Are you returning the appropriate flags from the model? http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/model-view-programming.html#making-the-model-editable

Comment: @KimBowlesSørhus: Yes, this seems to have been the problem. I guess I was focussing to much on the tutorials and not enough on the actual documentation. Everything works fine now. If you make this into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the model to be editable the edit flag need to be returned.

```
//Reimplement 
Qt::ItemFlag QAbstractItemModel::flags ( const QModelIndex & index ) const;
//and add 
Qt::ItemIsEditable 
//to the returned value
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#making-the-model-editable